# Is there a simple Jmeter performance test case for Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, jmeter

We are creating Jmeter performance benchmarking for our Cassandra installation.

For which we have been referring to the default Cassandra plugin mentioned in the [site](https://netflixtechblog.com/jmeter-plugin-for-cassandra-8ca848c0d480)

This plugin does not take any Cassandra server connection parameter for the "put", no much help is also present to how to use this plugin. [image: Please check the image]

**Some can help me with this plugin if any one knows how to configure Cassandra connection**

Hence we switched to an article to test Cassandra with Groovy. ([Link here](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/cassandra-load-testing-with-groovy))

This site calls to add multiple jar some are bundles and cannot find the exeat JAR

- snappy-java-1.0.5
- netty-transport-4.0.33.Final
- netty-handler-4.0.33.Final
- netty-common-4.0.33.Final
- netty-codec-4.0.33.Final
- netty-buffer-4.0.33.Final
- metrics-core-3.1.2
- lz4-1.2.0
- HdrHistogram-2.1.4
- guava-16.0.1

**Can some help me with some simpler test perform on Cassandra ?**

Answer (score 1):

For correct performance testing of Cassandra it's better to use specialized tools, like [NoSQLBench](https://github.com/nosqlbench/nosqlbench) that was developed specifically for that task.  Generic tools won't give you the real performance numbers.  Please read NoSQLBench documentation on how to correctly test Cassandra to take into account things like compaction, repairs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to [read documentation](https://github.com/Netflix/CassJMeter/wiki/getting_started) which mentions `CassandraProperties` configuration element where you can define your connection server parameters:

[image]

If you want to have the full control and not only be limited to what other guys implemented you can consider following instructions from [Cassandra Load Testing with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/cassandra-load-testing-with-groovy) article

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, started with this. The groovy article you shared is the some one with multiple JAR missing or not a correct link to the JAR.

Comment: The fist one with the Classendra plugin is giving FBConnection class not found , even after adding the Cassendra-all.jar from the maven repo it is still not working , so started with the second approach of using groovy script may jar dependency are still missing after adding the initial list. I am still going on adding JARs. Wondering if there will be a conflict of JARs in fist approach with the second approach or with the JMeter version I am currently using.